# Batch execution of stored procedures with out parameters Spring SimpleJdbcCall

Tags: java, spring-mvc, stored-procedures, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have case in which i need to batch insert using stored procedure with **out parameters**. In stored procedure we have conditional logic for create entry. So can any one tell me how can do with **SimpleJdbcCall**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring - Batch update using simplejdbccall while using Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46865291/spring-batch-update-using-simplejdbccall-while-using-stored-procedure)

Comment: @Nikolas i have seen this solution but its done with jdbctamplate. i'm looking for SimpleJdbcCall with out parameter

Comment: Okey, I am sorry. I retract my close vote then.